# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos objetos de javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: s]

Cree dos objetos exactamente iguales,pero el segundo con el success de ajax y la consola de chorme no los muestra igual y cuando utilizo los objetos para una función de grilla de un widget de jquery el primero funciona y el segundo no ¿Qué pasa?

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en el pequeño icono azul con una `i` al lado de donde marcas,
aparece una indicación de que el objeto se evaluó `justo ahora`.

Quiere decir que el valor mostrado en primera linea pudo haber cambiado desde que apareció en el log. El valor en la primera linea en cada entrada (`[2]` y `[]`) indica su valor en el momento que se genero el log (el primero tenia 2 elementos, y el segundo 0), pero cuando hiciste clic en ambas entradas, al abrirlos, se evalua nuevamente y muestra su valor actual.

Quiere decir que el segundo de ellos estaba *vacio* al momento de la evaluacion. Por ello no debe estar funcionando, revisa por que está vacio.

Si deseas que la consola muestre el valor completo de una variable al momento de evaluar, puedes usar:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))
```